# Scss classnames with special symbols like "[]"

Tags: css, sass, css-modules

This is a strange question. I request link type from server which might return "[TCP]" or "[UDP]". And I wanna use the string as classname directly for different background color like. What I want is :

```
<div className={`${styles.span} ${styles["[TCP]"]}`}/>
```

But the css selector ".[TCP]" is not allowed, below error given:

```
SassError: Invalid CSS after "&": expected selector, was ".[TCP]"
```

Now I am using `.replace(/\[|\]/g,"")` split the string "[TCP]" --> "TCP". But I hope someone can tell me another way or it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You can use `[TCP]` as classname."

As written [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) ([demo](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/crazy-class)) you can use any character for classname except NULL. All you have to do is in CSS write `\` before special characters. In your case, it would look like this `.\[TCP\]`.

But I believe it's much easier to just remove the special characters.